# Multiple Application Files in one Android app

Tags: java, android-manifest, android

I made three apps, which I now want to ship in one apk file (one installation). On startup of the "wrapper app" the user should decide which app to run.

So far, so good, but the problem is, each app is using global constants from an Application file. Is there a way to build the three apps into one, where each app uses its own application file?

Thanks!

To avoid confusion i add a short example:

App 1:

```
public class AApplication extends Application {
    public static String CONSTANT_1 = "aaa";
}
```

App 2:

```
public class BApplication extends Application {
public static String CONSTANT_1 = "bbb";
}
```

App 3:

```
public class CApplication extends Application {
    public static String CONSTANT_1 = "ccc";
}
```

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve.  Why 3 apps?  Why not one?

Comment: Three apps, because they are based on the same library project - the same codebase and they are doing almost the same, but look differetnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since the idea I head is obviously not realizable I came up with the following workaround:

1. I created an Apllication class in the new Project

   ```
   public class NewApplication extends OldSuperApplication {}
   ```
2. I added a method

   ```
   public static void setApplication(RGCApplication a) {
       CONSTANT_1 = a.CONSTANT_1;
       ...
   }
   ```
3. after selecting the desired "sub-app" on the startscreen in this case application "A" i call

   ```
   NewApplication.setApplication(new AApplication());
   ```

   or

   ```
   NewApplication.setApplication(new BApplication());
   ```

I'm not sure if this is smelly coding or not, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want three activity that can be launched. Add in the manifest something like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activityone"
        android:label="First Activity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
        android:name=".Activitysecond"
        android:label="Second Activity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
        android:name=".Activitythree"
        android:label="Third Activity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In this way user has **three** icons (activity) to click.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Giuseppe, but that's not was I was looking for. Each of this apps consists of several activities. But the problem is the application class. Each app uses multiple constants which are defined in the application class. the names of the contstatns are the same (that's why i can't put them into one application file) but the values are different.

Comment: Your application class can be shared with the three activities. if they are constant, make it static and you can retrieve them easily.

Comment: But i have three Application classes with various constant that have the same name, but different values for eacht class. Eg. public static string CONSTANT_1 = "aaa"; in the next application class the same constant has value "bbb" and in the third class the value is "ccc"... i need the ability to somehow combine the three apps with the three different application classes into one...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what's the issue. If you've constants, you can make the three application static and you can retrieve values with Application1.CONSTANT_1 , Aplication2.CONSTANT_1 etc.

Comment: You're right, that's what I basically did now. The issue was, to initialize them on startup in the way Android does it with ONE (singleton) Application class. But as i mentioned in my answer above i solved this issue by setting the concerning app constants after selecting an app. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I read your update, it works, but... If they are constants I don't understand why you need three object. imho you only need three static class.

Answer (score 0):

You can not integrate 3 different apk and its respective code-base to run by single apk, either integrate all 3 code-base in single application and divide all 3 as different modules to run depending upon selection by user.

Comment: what do you mean by "all 3 as different modules"?

Comment: Modules in concept of java, clubbed source code to achieve any specific functionality

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i think this is a Android specific problem where i have to find a soluton to bring the three different Application classes into one Android project. As mentioned in the Comment below each Android project has one Application class (singleton) and i - since originally each app was a standalone - have three applicatin classes, where the constants hav the same names but different values for each Aplication class.

Comment: Exactly, android app follows singleton pattern and hence you cannot have more than 1 applicaton level class for an application/apk.