# Android: one app for multiple uses via parameters in AndroidManifest

Tags: delphi, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

It is possible to register one (Delphi) app for multiple uses, with more than one icon in App Chooser? For instance like this:

- register app to open some file types (I know how to do that)
- register to open/acces to any file, but App Chooser should show icon different than main app icon, and different text, not the app name - for instance "Base 64 encode/decode file"
- same thing, for text files or other documents/images compatible with operation - "Convert to pdf"

All functionality is built in the same app, but operation, and icon in the App Choser, should depend of parameter passed in intent, as EXTRA_TEXT for instance. For instance, if EXTRA_TEXT is "b64enc" the app should auto encode the file on intent EncodedPath, then save base 64 encoded file in app documents folder, notify user "conversion complete", then close itself.

For example, app can use file extension to choose what to do with the file, but this is not enough for functionality I need.

I have seen this answer

[Multiple Application Files in one Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137892/multiple-application-files-in-one-android-app)

and it is OK as some kind of guidance, but not really an answer on this question :-)

In Windows the same application can register itself in Win context menu for multiple purposes with different icons and different context menu text, and same program can do different operations on the file, depends on parameter passed to the program.

So, it is possible in Android, maybe via AndroidManifest, or I shoud use different approach? And if I must, is it possible to have multiple activities in Delphi app for Android?

Edit: I have found this blog

https://blog.andreamagni.eu/2019/02/how-to-add-android-app-shortcuts-to-a-fmx-application/

and looks like maybe it is possible by using shortcuts

Comment: I don't think multiple activities is supported. You could just show a different form on startup depending on what is in the intent.